# Pandas does not retain frequency format when exporting to excel

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, datetime-format, resampling

I have a monthly dataframe and after resampling to annual data, I used Pandas to_period('M') to have index shown in monthly format. That works fine. When I export to excel, it is in datetime format there. 
How to retain the  format when exporting to excel.

Data sample in Jupyter Notebook:

```
2014  1463  146.416667  1110.877414  197.230546  199.230546
```

Data sample in excel:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00 1463    146.416667  1110.877414 197.230546  199.230546
```

Comment: Try to convert from datetime to object or string.

Comment: Thanks @Vaishali dor editing the question!

Answer (score 0):

@Arthur Gouveia: Thanks for your response!

I tried to change the data type to string and worked. But any better solution?

```
if type(TNA_BB2_a.index)==pd.tseries.period.PeriodIndex:
    TNA_BB2_a.index = TNA_BB2_a.index.strftime('%Y')
if type(tna_n_m_BB.index)==pd.tseries.period.PeriodIndex:
    tna_n_m_BB.index = tna_n_m_BB.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
```